# Dimension of the spanned subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}.$ Determine the dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ generated by the following vectors.

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\1\\2\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2\\5\\1\\3\\1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 5\\8\\3\\6\\2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\\1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\2a-b+2\\-a+b-1\\-a+2b-1\\3a-2b \end{pmatrix}.$$

My stategy is to construct the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 5 &2 &0\\
  2 & 5 & 8 &1 &2a-b+2\\
  1& 1 & 3 &1 &-a+b-1\\
  2 & 3 & 6 &1 &-a+2b-1\\
  0 &1 &2 &1 &3a-2b
\end{pmatrix}

and compute its rank by row reduction. Since the rank of the matrix above should be equal to the dimension of its column space, then in theory this computation should give the dimension of the subspace being asked. Is my strategy correct?

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, that is the quickest/most common method to compute the dimension of the subspace generated by those vectors :)

Comment: Thank you. While the strategy is straightforward, I think certain complications rise after you reduce one of the rows to all zeroes except the last entry which depends on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Well, you're in a case where the answer will indeed depend on $a$ and $b$. You could here notice that the first $4$ vectors that do not depend on $a$ and $b$ are not linearly independent already (you could get rid of two of them) and be left with computing the rank a $3\times 5$ matrix. But in all fairness, I don't know if it makes the computations any easier...

Comment: @Arthur I get $3$ for the rank of those four vectors.

Comment: You might be right, it's quite likely I messed up my computations haha. The thing is: you can dispose of at least one of them

Comment: I did some computations, and it seems like the rank is either 3 or 4, depending on a and b.